# G Suite Service Account Fails Requests But Delegation Works?

Tags: oauth-2.0, credentials, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-groups

I have followed the documentation for creating a G Suite Service Account. The following works fine to emulate a given user in my domain:

```
def create_directory_service(user_email):

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
        scopes = SCOPES)

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    return build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

However, I want to be able to just use the service account to access domain information *without* needing to emulate a particular user. But if I pass in the service account's email address (as given in its key file), I just get `HttpError 503: "Service unavailable. Please try again"`.

I've added the service account's email address as a `Service Account Admin`, but it still doesn't work. Again, delegation works fine, but not using the service account directly.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

To use Directory API, you must use delegation to impersonate a user in the domain, that can use Directory API (so usually an admin).